# Is there a way to use the ffmpeg binary/unix executable in a py2app application to run ffmpeg on computers without it installed?

Tags: python-3.x, ffmpeg, py2app, pydub, gtts

I wrote a small python script that is essentially just a text to speech script. It uses the pydub - audiosegment python library to convert the mp3 from gTTS to an ogg that can be played in pygame. A link to my github repository can be found here: https://github.com/AnupPlays/TTS

this is the main function:

```
def webscrape():
    global x
    global b
    b.state(['disabled'])
    src = "sound.mp3"
    dst = "sound.ogg"
    murl = str(url.get())
    response = requests.get(murl)
    response.raise_for_status()

    parse = bs4.BeautifulSoup(response.text, 'html.parser')
    x = str(parse.get_text())
    print(x)
    text = gTTS(x)
    text.save("sound.mp3")
    AudioSegment.from_mp3(src).export(dst, format='ogg')
    b.state(['!disabled'])
```

this is a list of my imports:

```
#Imports
import os
import sys
import pygame

#google text to speech
from gtts import gTTS

#requests and BeautifulSoup
import requests
import bs4

#pygame audio player
from pygame import mixer

#tkinter ui
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import filedialog
from tkinter import messagebox

#mp3 -> wav
from os import path
from pydub import AudioSegment
```

Answer (score 0):

For anyone wondering using homebrew you can get the dependencies for this and copy those dependencies into your packager.

Comment: Hi, your answer lacks details. Please have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer and edit your answer accordingly.